# Return User Roles from Azure App Registration when Authenticating from SPFX with AadTokenProvider

Tags: spfx, authentication, azure-ad

I have the following code on my web part:

```
import { AadHttpClient, AadHttpClientFactory, AadTokenProviderFactory } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

const factory: AadHttpClientFactory = this.context.aadHttpClientFactory;
const client: AadHttpClient = await factory.getClient(AppSettings.clientId);
const tokenProviderFactory: AadTokenProviderFactory = this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory;
const tokenProvider = await tokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
let token = null;

try {
  // Request the "roles" claim in the access token
  token = await tokenProvider.getToken(AppSettings.clientId);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

however, the returned token does not contain the custom permissions this app has on azure It has some app roles where we include the users and I'd like for them to be returned when callign the api as claims to facilitate role management
App roles example on the app manifest:

````
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Viewers group",
            "displayName": "Viewers",
            "id": "225ba58e-cd21-43df-b25b-d60cd2c8e4f5",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "Viewers.Group"
        },```
````